# Unable to load Amcharts in IE 11

Tags: amcharts

I am using amcharts in firefox and chrome its working fine but in IE 10, 11 its not showing the charts. There is no error message as well in console.

Does anyone faced same issue? Will appreciate help in this regard.

Comment: I have charts showing fine in all the major browsers.  Can you include the script you are using to show the graphs as could be an error somewhere in your code?

Comment: What version of amcharts are you using?

Comment: I am using amcharts 3.10.0